# monitor websphere with loadrunner 11.0

Tags: performance, websphere, monitor, loadrunner

I want to monitor the websphere 6.1 with JDK 1.5 using loadrunner. since loadrunner V8 only support the JDK1.4, so I have to setup loadrunner V11. 
but after competed installation, and open controller, no websphere monitor in available graphs, only MS asp and Weblogic monitor can be selected. for Websphere, only MQ for monitor.

the question is, does loadrunner V11.0 support websphere application server monitor? If can, how to configure it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use LoadRunner 8.1 to monitor the websphere6.1, it works now.